# excel result and stats test are not the same for p-value

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, p-value, t-test, scipy.stats

I'm trying to get the same result from this excel table, indicating that there's a link between the wight and the result (after going to the gym)

[image]

The result on the excel shows the p-value as 1.28% (for 2 tails) and 0.64% for 1 tail.

Given

```
weight = np.array([70,71,76,84,72,78,79,80,74,75])
result = np.array([67,70,77,80,70,79,70,77,70,70])
```

and then I do:

```
stats.ttest_ind(B,A)
```

and I get

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=4.413795011355454, pvalue=0.00015789925499823287)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I run `ttest_rel(weight, result)` on your sample (which is a paired t-test, the same as what you appear to be implementing in Excel), I get the same t-statistic and p-value as in your Excel output.

Comment: Also, you may know this, but t-tests examine whether there are significant differences between two group means for one variable.  Based on your wording, you may need to calculate correlation between two variables instead.

Comment: A paired t test is needed here, instead of the independent sample t-test that you have coded for. To understand the difference in the simplistic terms, a paired t-test is used in cases where the two samples belong to the same set of individuals or items, independent t-test means that the two samples are independent of each other (can't be the same individuals before and after any study)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in one of the comments, you need to perform a [paired-sample/related-sample t-test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html).

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
weight = np.array([70,71,76,84,72,78,79,80,74,75])
result = np.array([67,70,77,80,70,79,70,77,70,70])
stats.ttest_rel(weight, result)
# TtestResult(statistic=3.0972820171137343, pvalue=0.012778381715135633, df=9)
```

It tests the null hypothesis that the *population mean of differences* (between corresponding observations) is zero, whereas the independent sample t-test tests the null hypothesis that the *difference between the population means* is zero.

If the alternative hypothesis is one-sided, use the `alternative` parameter. For instance, if the alternative is that the population mean of differences is greater than zero,

```py
stats.ttest_rel(weight, result, alternative='greater'
# TtestResult(statistic=3.0972820171137343, pvalue=0.0063891908575678166, df=9)
```